# where is located the 'module' command?

Tags: environment-modules

I am sorry if this is a silly question, but I can't locate where's the "module" command for the modules environment. "which module", "whereis module", or "alias module" gives me nothing.

This is very puzzling to me, can anyone please help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$> type module
module is a function
module () 
{ 
    eval `/usr/bin/modulecmd bash $*`
}
```

I guess I have to thank whoever marked my question as lazy. It made me read the whole modules documentation where I found the answer :)